# upgrade to webpack 4, splitchunks

Tags: webpack

I had running `commonsChunkPlugin`

```
module.exports = {                                                                                                                                                                  
  context: __dirname,

   entry: {

   vendor: [
     "site_common/js/share-button/share.js",                                                                                                                                           "moment",
     "site_common/js/kakaolink-web/kakao.link.js",                                                                                                                                       "jquery",
       'django',                                                                                                                                                                         'nativeAppUtils',
     ],

     'vendor_react': [
       'react',
       'react-dom',
       'redux',
       'react-redux',
       'redux-thunk',
       'react-router',
       'react-router-redux',
       'react-intl',
       'normalizr',
       'lodash',
       'site_common/utils/fetch',
       'classnames',
       'react-day-picker',
       'redux-form',

       'immutability-helper',
       'semantic-ui-react',
     ],
}

plugins: [
     new CommonsChunkPlugin({
       names: ["vendor_backbone", "vendor_react", "vendor"],
       minChunks: Infinity
     }),
]
```

Now I am upgrading to webpack 4 and the output file size is like 4Mb, whereas it was about 300k with webpack 2.

I have the following, and can't proceed to where to change

```
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor_backbone: {
          name: 'vendor_backbone',
          test: 'vendor_backbone',
          enforce: true,
          chunks: 'all'
        },
        vendor_react: {
          name: 'vendor_react',
          test: 'vendor_react',
          enforce: true,
          chunks: 'all'
        },
        vendor: {
          name: 'vendor',
          test: 'vendor',
          enforce: true,
          chunks: 'all'
        },
      }
    },
    noEmitOnErrors: true,
    minimize: false,                                                                                                                                                                },
```

Comment: I am having exactly same issue. After inspecting the bundle size with https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer, I can see that there are duplicated packages inside of the bundle. Which would make sense if they are different versions, but Webpack 2 did not do that. I have being struggling for a day now - and no luck - I am getting 5.5mb build instead of 3

Comment: I was looking at output from webpack nd from bundle-analyzer, which was showing package duplication and bungle being bigger on webpack 4. 
But as it turns out, even if sizes were different, after I put it in prod environment, size of the file downloaded by browser was the same... strange